# Casting String to Integer not working, throwing NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android

The value of walletBalance is a string, eg "150.0".

I am trying to display an error message in form of a toast in another activity(SuccessActivity) is the amount to be withdrawn from the user is less than the wallet balance. I keep getting NumberFormatException error for the value of i, so i decided to use a try catch block but it still doesnt work. Here is the method below.

```
 private void checkWalletBalance(int amount, Context context){
        String walletBalance = Preferences.getBalance(context);

                try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(walletBalance.trim());
                    if(amount < i){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SuccessActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Toast. makeText(ActivityHome.this,"Insufficient Wallet Balance",Toast. LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());

        }


    }
```

Alos, I want to display a toast in the success Activity, If the condition i true. here is the code in success activity to display  the toast message.

```
    private void insufficientError(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();

        Toast.makeText(SuccessActivity.this,"Insufficient  Balance",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: `150` is an Int `150.0` is not

Comment: "The value of walletBalance is a string" why not use an int, or a BigDecimal, or something else which more naturally represents a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**NumberFormatException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) - Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

**Don't**

```
 int i = Integer.parseInt(walletBalance.trim());  //walletBalance.trim() ==150.0
```

**Do**

```
   int i = (int) Double.parseDouble(walletBalance.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Blackbelt commented, you are trying to parse a double string and not an integer.

Therefore, you need to do the following:

`double amount = Double.parseDouble(walletBalance.trim());`

Answer (score 1):

You could use either of the following-

```
Double.valueOf(walletBalance.trim());
Double.parseDouble(walletBalance.trim());
```

And then if you want to convert them to Integer/int like this -

```
Integer i = Double.valueOf(walletBalance.trim()).intValue();
int i = (int) Double.parseDouble(walletBalance.trim());
```

Comment: No point in using `Double.valueOf` in the first case. Just do `(int) Double.parseDouble` as well, to avoid creating the `Double` instance.